Trouble clicking "Event" button using injected javacript in browser in google calendar
My work is to click on the "event" button after clicking on "Create" button on Google calendar.

Here is my script, which can be run on console or scripty:
console.log("Loading script to open event in Google Calendar");

function openEvent() {
    // Open the dropdown by clicking on the create button
    var createButton = document.querySelector('div[aria-label="Create"]');
    if (createButton) {
        createButton.click();
        console.log("Create button clicked");
    } else {
        console.log("Create button not found");
        return;
    }

    // Wait for the dropdown to open
    setTimeout(() => {
        // Select the event element within the dropdown
        var eventButton = document.querySelector('body > div.JPdR6b.QFf4q.qjTEB > div > div > span:nth-child(1) > div.uyYuVb.oJeWuf > div');
        if (eventButton) {
            eventButton.click();
            console.log("Event opened");
        } else {
            console.log("Event element not found in dropdown");
        }
    }, 2000); // Wait for 2 seconds before clicking 
}

const scriptContent = `
    (${openEvent.toString()})();
`;

const script = document.createElement('script');
script.textContent = scriptContent;
document.head.appendChild(script);
console.log("Script to open event in Google Calendar added");

Unfortunately, the console says "Event opened" but the event button is NOT getting clicked, as shown in this gif:


You code simply can not write Event opened to the console, without having executed eventButton.click() first. Maybe Google uses a different event handler on that element. But whatever you are trying to do there, should probably not be done by trying to "remote control" the UI, but via the appropriate APIs instead.

If you look at the Google calendar html code in the console, you will see that there is no event listener attached to that div. So calling .click() on it will have no affect. The code must have a click event handler higher up in the DOM hierarchy that you'll have to find.

@RayWallace thank you for the reply, I'll check and rewrite the code

@RayWallace i changed querySelector to div[aria-label="Event"] but still doesn't work. It says "Event element not found in dropdown"

I would have thought that document.querySelector('[aria-label="Event"]').click() would do it, but it does not seem to. I reckon that you will have to do what @CBroe pointed out, you could look into using their API.

Okay I'll look into it

Edit
After having provided my fist solution, which does work, proved by the logging, I installed the  scripty plugin and run the changed script out of curiosity.
Only then I realized that the OP actually wants to open the "new event" layer.
What can be said is, that regardless of whether one dispatches a new click event via eventButton.dispatchEvent(new Event('click')); or one just does invoke eventButton.click() neither of the techniques achieves the wanted outcome, which most probably is due to none of the generated and consumed/operated events is trusted.
Only events which are created by real UI interactions have implemented a non writable/configurable isTrusted get handler which does return the boolean true value. The isTrusted property can not be spoofed for events which are created synthetically by e.g. scripting.
Google's implementation most probably checks/scans all of the critical events for exactly this isTrusted property value.
Note
The following formerly provided solutions solves the timing problem but can not solve the problem of how to trigger the raising of the "new event" layer itself.
... former answer ...

In order to achieve successfully triggered click-events for each button, one has to query each button and then to trigger each button's click.
But the difference comes with the correct timing.
Whereas one can immediately query the create-button, add an event-handler to it and trigger the click-event, one has to wait for the create-button's related menu to be opened first, before querying and triggering the event-button. Thus, one has to delay all event-button specific tasks within the create-button's additionally registered click-handler.
Note ... one also has to be aware that the querying as it is right now depends on language/locale specific attribute selectors. As for the OP it is English, matching the targeted word exactly as is. The next provided example code extends the selector by German as well, with both queries being set to case insensitive.
function openEvent() {
  // Open the dropdown by clicking on the create button

  const createButton = document
    .querySelector('div[role="button"][aria-label="create" i], div[role="button"][aria-label="eintragen" i]');

  console.log({ createButton });

  createButton?.addEventListener?.('click', ({ currentTarget }) => {
    console.log('create button ... ', { currentTarget }, ' ... has been clicked.');

    setTimeout(() => {

      const eventButton = document
        .querySelector('div[role="menu"] span[aria-label="event" i], div[role="menu"] span[aria-label="termin" i]');

      console.log({ eventButton });

      eventButton?.addEventListener?.('click', ({ currentTarget }) =>
        console.log('event button ... ', { currentTarget }, ' ... has been clicked.')
      );
      eventButton?.dispatchEvent?.(new Event('click'));
      //eventButton?.click?.();

    }, 1000);
  });
  createButton?.click?.();
}


